# How to connect to XMPP server using PHP

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire

I have set up an XMPP server, I have created the login form. PHP and HTML. I have not done this before, I want to know how to connect to XMPP server through PHP just like connecting to MySQL using PHP.

Comment: `XMPP` is server just like `Apache`.

Comment: Hi try to follow http://youtu.be/o1dskkC1wdI

Comment: @nino did not asked what is XMPP. He asked how to make a connection to it using PHP.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(0);  // some time connection take while  
require_once 'xmpp-lib/XMPPHP/XMPP.php';  
$host = 'you Host name'; // ex.192.168.2.1  
$port = '5222'; // its defauls xmpp port 
$username = 'name@host' // ex vivek@host 
$pass = 'userpass';  
$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP(host , $port, $username, $pass, 'xmpphp','yourhost', $printlog=false, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);  
try {
         $conn->connect();
         $conn->processUntil('session_start');
         $conn->presence();
         $conn->message('anotherusername@host', 'Hello!');
         $conn->disconnect(); 
} catch(XMPPHP_Exception $e) {
         die($e->getMessage()); 
} 
?>`enter code here`
```

Comment: is it possible to integrate xmpp protocol with php web service to pass data over tcp/ip protocol?

Comment: XMPP is made to go over TCP/IP by design.